# How do you protect your WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new to WordPress plugins. Not PHP been doing that for a while.

I'm making good progress but it just occurred to me. The plugin essentially dumps a bunch of PHP files onto your WordPress server so anyone that has access to the root can see your code and hence copy it if they wanted to.

How would you protect against this in a plugin? Is it even possible?

I'd be interested to know what the general consensus is

Comment: You basically cannot hide your code in interpreted languages. Everyone with access to your server is going to have access to your code.

Comment: I thought that was the case.Thanks for getting back to me, It just puzzled me that any plugin would have the same problem and it would be a massive job to update free plugins to remove ad's etc

Comment: @NoahBoegli - this is not true. See my answer below.

Comment: @azernik I did not understand his question the way you did then. I thought he was asking to hide the code from the people having access (FTP/SFTP) to the server.

Comment: @NoahBoegli Yes that's exactly what I was asking. If they can access the files they can access your plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use access limiting to mark directories as only containing scripts (i.e. tell the server that it should only serve the result of execution, not the raw content).

In Apache, you do this by adding a `Deny from all` directive for files that you don't want the user to be accessing by name at all, and ensuring that any files that are entry-points to your code have a .php or .php3 file extension.

Comment: I'm on a Windows server :)